# Error converting ajax request into Ruby (Incoming message has an unexpected format 'Raw')

Tags: ruby, ajax, rest-client

I'm in the process of converting an ajax request into Ruby using [RestClient](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client)

Functions in Javascript

```
var dispatchWebAPIEndpointURL = 'http://dispatchweb.eureka-technology.fr/webmanager/WCFDispatchAPI.svc/REST/';
function APICallPOST(Method, Data, OnSucces, OnError) {
    $.ajax(
            {
                url: dispatchWebAPIEndpointURL + 'json/' + Method,
                type: 'POST',
                data: Data,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: OnSucces,
                failure: OnError
            });
}
function Authentification() {

    var AuthentificationRequest = new Object();
    AuthentificationRequest.Credential = new Object();
    AuthentificationRequest.Credential.License = "license";
    AuthentificationRequest.Credential.Login = "login";
    AuthentificationRequest.Credential.Password = "password";
    AuthentificationRequest.Credential.EMail = null;
    AuthentificationRequest.Credential.Language = 'fr-FR';


    APICallPOST('Authentify', JSON.stringify(AuthentificationRequest), function (response) {
        if (response.Status == 200 && response.Authentified == true) {
            alert('Authentification success');
        }
        else {
            alert(response.Errors[0]);
        }
    },
    function (response) {
        alert('Error');
    });

}
```

Functions in Ruby using RestClient

```
url = 'http://dispatchweb.eureka-technology.fr/webmanager/WCFDispatchAPI.svc/REST/';
credential = {
      "Credential" => {
        "License"   => "License",
        "Login"     => "Login",
        "Password"  => "Password",
        "EMail"     => nil,
        "Language"  => "en-EN"
      }
    }
request_url = url + "json/Authentify"
    headers = {
      contentType: "application/json",
      dataType: "json"
    }
    RestClient.post(request_url, credential.to_json, headers) {|response, request, result, &block|
      case response.code
      when 200
        p "It worked !"
        response
      when 423
        raise SomeCustomExceptionIfYouWant
      else
        p "you messed up"
        response.return!(request, result, &block)
      end
    }
```

The javascript functions work fine, and I get a response for success. The ruby version keeps giving me the 500 error along with the message

> "Exception caught at WCFDispatchWebAPIErrorHandler & # xD; \ nMethod:
>   DeserializeRequest & # xD; \ nMessage: The incoming message has an
>   unexpected format 'Raw'. The message formats expected for the op \ XC3
>   \ xA9ration are 'XML'; 'Json'."

I'm wondering if I actually pass in the credential in a correct way.

Any thought would be appreciated! Thanks!

**Solved**
So it turns out

```
headers = {
          contentType: "application/json",
          dataType: "json"
        }
```

should be

```
headers = {
          content_type: "application/json",
          data_type: "json"
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Where you have:

```
headers = {
  contentType: "application/json",
  dataType: "json"
}
```

it should be

```
headers = {
  content_type: "application/json",
  data_type: "json"
}
```